# intercept TCP/UDP Packets on a host before they are sent to or recevied from the network

Tags: networking, tcp

for example,
1
when I'm using some programs, like visiting websites using firefox
if the webserver send my program some data, my program TCP stack will issue 
an ACK packet. Is it possible to intercept this ACK packet, modify it and then send it out

2 when a program receives some tcp data or tcp ack packet from network, is it possible
to intercept these packets and then deliver them to the program TCP stack?

someone says Deep packet Inspection(DPI) is OK, is it true or not?
DPI can be deployed in a PC like laptop?
so What I'm trying to do is like to add a layer between the network and the TCP stack of a machine.

thanks!

Comment: What OS?  This is possible via netfilter on Linux.

Comment: On Windows, I have used a product that does packet tagging to aid in parental controls.  So it is possible on Windows too, but not easy.  I believe you need to create a NDIS filter driver.  Drivers must be programmed in C/C++, and the base footprint it ~ 10,000 lines of code (at least that what a friend of mine told me who used to write Windows drivers for Microsoft).

Comment: wow, on linux is already great! so are there any example source codes? beside, if there are universal solution for all OS, that's better!

Comment: if I just want to intercept ACK packet, is it easier to find a simple and universal solution?

Comment: You won't be able to write a single solution that works on all platforms (e.g., Linux, Windows, OSX, etc.).  However, a single driver should work for all versions of Windows.  Although, you'll have to create a 32-bit and 64-bit driver to support both types of Windows.

Comment: Here's a link where someone is asking how to filter URLs, regardless of the browser used.  Different concept, similar solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414751/url-stop-using-delphi-service, and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565492(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: ok, I just want to filter TCP/udp level-packets, URL is application-level. besides, is netfilter a DPI solution or it is easier to master than DPI or not? I need a easy-to-learn solution.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with DPI solutions.  But the concept as you describe it is very similar to an NDIS filter driver, which lets you intercept packets and do something with them...  I realize you don't want to filter URLs.  I pasted the link because of the discussion about filter drivers.

Comment: If you search for `Linux netfilter` (as suggested by @Zoredache), you'll see that there is a Windows port (http://netfilterforwin.sourceforge.net/).  Perhaps that's an easier solution to implement than a NDIS Filter Driver.  Good luck!